# Email notification from existing SQL-based application

Tags: c#, .net, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm trying to establish my best option for using email notifications with an existing bespoke CRM application.

Essentially what I want to do is send an email to an affected user when one of their work items has breached its KPI (key performance indicator).

Am I best to do this by using an SQL trigger and a stored procedure (can they both be used to achieve this?) or should I use some c# coding and a scheduled task? Or am I missing an easier route?

Comment: You'll need to enter which make and version of SQL Server you are using. Certainly for SQL Server the answer depends heavily on the version (as `xp_sendmail` was removed).

Comment: What would an example of a KPI be?  Will probably scale better and be more maintainable if you have a separate service polling the data.  Depends mostly on your requirements.

Comment: Apologies, it would be using SQL Server 2005. Which still has xp_sendmail if I remember correctly, what is the replacement in present times, db_mail?

Comment: An example would be query resolution, a member of staff may have a KPI of 5 days turnaround on a query, a breach of 4 days would require an email to be sent to the member of staff to prioritise that piece of work.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before using a windows service which polls the database every minute and then composes and sends emails.

I guess a trigger is another possible approach but what if sending the email fails? You'd probably want some sort of fall back like the scheduled task approach anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like Quartz.Net, which is a scheduling engine. This has the ability to run tasks at defined intervals/at defined times, and also to re-try if a task fails, or alert you in some way.

Quartz.Net is available via NuGet (or Add Library Package) and has lots of good documentation on their [site](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use a SQL Agent job to compose the emails and then dispatch. This way you can specify certain credentials for the job to run (e.g. access to the mail server), and you can have it run as often as you like.

The method I currently use is a simple CLR stored procedure that utilises the SMTP functionality in .Net and this takes a bunch of parameters that construct the email message.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking the best way to send an email in SQL Server 2005, I think [msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail] is your friend.  You can do a quick search on the web to get the particulars, but you must have database mail setup correctly before using it.  I used it with tsqlunit to run a nightly job to catch if some business rules were in compliance.

If instead you're looking for a good way of catching events to be able to send an email notification, it all depends on your setup and how often you want this check to occur.  It could be something you attach to an already existing stored procedure, or you could use a trigger (if your setup can handle it).  Sometimes it's better to start out small and migrate to something better after some lessons are learned.

Hope this helps!